# ${\frak h}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a solvable lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Show that
$${\frak h}_n(\mathbb{C}) = 
\lbrace A\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C}) : A_{i,j} = 0\text{ if } i\geqslant j \rbrace.$$

is solvable Lie algebra.

Comment: It is solvable, but not nilpotent. This has been shown at [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114428/some-solvable-lie-algebra-but-not-nilpotent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are lower triangular matrices. Your $\mathfrak{h}_n$ has a basis
consisting of $E_{i,j}$ where $i-j\ge1$. Denote the space of matrices
spanned by the $E_{i,j}$ with $i-j\ge k$  as $L_k$. Show that $[L_k,L_k]
\subseteq L_{2k}$.